# How to define an cell equivalent with `using cell = pair<void*, cell*>`?

Tags: c++

By the C++ standard **n3376**, the following code is ill-formed.

```
using cell = pair<void*, cell*>; // ill-formed
```

Is there any way to implement `cell`, which is an reasonable data structure, without defining an new `cell` class in C++?

Comment: It seems you are asking, "How can I trick the compiler into thinking ill-formed code is well-formed code?"

Comment: @RSahu, actually this is an common used structure similar with `LinkedListNode`. And an easy implementation is useful.

Comment: Can you use a custom `pair`?

Comment: @PasserBy, yes, I can. This is an similar example in my project.

Comment: @ZijingWu, the main difference is that what you are defining is a type alias. It does not define a type. `LinkedListNode` is a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, your only option is inheritance, i.e.

```
struct cell : std::pair<void*,cell*> { };
```

If you need `cell` to be of the same type as `std::pair<void*,cell*>`, you could cast the former to the latter at the point where that matters.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to define cell as a  class. Also, I don't think you are allowed to derive from `std::pair`.

Comment: I know, but I thought it'd be more productive to show him this, then to just say *no*.

Comment: "I don't think you are allowed to derive from `std::pair`". Why? `std::pair` is not `final` in the standard.

Comment: I can't find the section of the library that talks about being able/unable to derived from classes defined in the standard library.

Comment: @RSahu That's just a general guideline. The rational is that since the standard does not prescribe library implementation, one could get unexpected behavior, because member variables or functions can be overshadowed. Here, we are not adding anything new to the struct, so it's completely safe.

Comment: @RSahu Also, there are types in the standard library that are actually meant to be inherited. Here's a discussion on SO https://stackoverflow.com/q/1073958/2640636

Comment: From the accepted answer of that post: "If it doesn't have any virtual methods, then you shouldn't be using it as a base."

Comment: Nothing ventured, nothing gained.

Answer (score 2):

At the cost of (quite some) readability, you may use a custom `pair` and some specialization to achieve something similar

```
struct self {};

template<typename F, typename S>
struct pair
{
    F first;
    S second;

    // ...
};

template<typename F>
struct pair<F, self*> : pair<F, pair*>
{
};
```

And you write

```
using cell = pair<void*, self*>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use

```
using cell = pair<void*, void*>;
```

and then cast the second element to the right type when necessary. You could write a function for that, like

```
cell& get_cell(cell& x) {
  return *static_cast<cell*>(x.second);
}
```