# Extend std::vector with range checking and signed size_type

Tags: c++

I would like to use a class with the same functionality as std::vector, but

- Replace `std::vector<T>::size_type` by some *signed* integer (like `int64_t` or simply `int`), instead of usual `size_t`. It is very annoying to see warnings produced by a compiler in comparisons between signed and unsigned numbers when I use standard vector interface. I can't just disable such warnings, because they really help to catch programming errors.
- put `assert(0 <= i && i < size());` inside `operator[](int i)` to check out of range errors. As I understand it will be a better option over the call to `.at()` because I can disable assertions in release builds, so performance will be the same as in the standard implementation of the vector. It is almost impossible for me to use `std::vector` without manual checking of range before each operation because `operator[]` is the source of almost all weird errors related to memory access.

The possible options that come to my mind are to

1. Inherit from std::vector. It is not a good idea, as said in the following question: [Extending the C++ Standard Library by inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073958/extending-the-c-standard-library-by-inheritance?noredirect=1&lq=1).
2. Use composition (put std::vector inside my class) and repeat all the interface of `std::vector`. This option forces me to think about the current C++ standard, because the interface of some methods, iterators is slightly different in C++ 98,11,14,17. I would like to be sure, that when c++ 20 became available, I can simply use it without reimplementation of all the interface of my vector.

Comment: Given your choices, I'd go for the composition approach.   You can control the interface, provide only a subset of operations that are meaningful for your program rather than EVERY operation that `std::vector` provides.   However, your rationale for this (avoiding indexing using `unsigned` values) is rather weak.  I suggest you consider learning more about use of iterators rather than relying on array indexing (use of `operator[]` or `vec.at()`) - doing so avoids a lot of problems associated with array indexing syntax - including the `signed`/`unsigned` concerns.

Comment: A can't see a specific question here? BTW, There is really no problem with implementing a *vector* class inheriting from `std::vector` as a means of implementation. The problem comes when you want to use that polymorphically so just don't do that. And why would you? There is no reason to create vectors dynamically. If you're hyper paranoid, then just use private inheritance (slightly more work but not much)

Comment: Firstly, instead of *"`int64_t` or simply `int`"* I propose `std::ptrdiff_t` which is essentially "a signed `size_t`". Also, I'd avoid adding range checks manually. Most `vector` implementations have *conditional* range checks that can be enabled one way or another. (E. g. GCC's libstdc++ uses `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` for that.)

Comment: Also don't use indexes use iterators. (unless you absolutely can't avoid it). And then you can avoid your problem by using `for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)` - problem solved :)

Comment: why someone want to have sized size? Why someone wants to compare with sized ints? There is no sense to have a negative amount of data...

Comment: @Klaus It is very convenient to write decreasing loops `for (int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: @BhavinChirag: It is very bad code! `for(auto& element: vec ) should be your friend! If size is zero you simple access out of bounds. So your code is simply wrong!

Comment: @Peter Regarding idea with iterators: aren't they supposed to be used in generic code? As I understand, if I definitely know that I use only a vector, the code is simpler to read when it is written with indices, not iterators.

Comment: This can help with reverse iteration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542591/c11-reverse-range-based-for-loop

Comment: Iterators should always be preferred over indexing. They are generally safer and you should be leveraging the *algorithms* from the standard library anyway.

Comment: @BhavinChirag: If code can be generic, why someone should write non generic code. In your case it is slower, has flows and needs additional checks which leads you derive from stl container. So you are completly on the wrong way. You abuse the interface, find the abuse complicated, as this you try to modify the interface and extend the trouble again and again. I would advice you to use the containers in the intended fashion. This will stop all your work arrounds for problems you introduce your self!

Comment: @Klaus The use of range based `for` is great (and as @drescherjm noted that it can be reversed), however, it is not possible to get an index of the current iteration. For example, I don't know how to write in a ranged-based for way: `for (int i = a.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) { a[i] = 2 * a[i+1]; }`. I assume here that `a.size() >= 2` is checked earlier.

Comment: Maybe my last example is not great and the code actually can be rewritten without dependence of indices, but the general idea is that there are cases when it is really the easiest way to write and read code.

Comment: @BhavinChirag -  if you're going to use a non-generic approach over a generic approach, that non-generic approach has to provide advantages over the generic approach.   Problem is, array indexing is a specific approach that offers several disadvantages over using iterators, and relatively few advantages.  Hence iterators are usually considered preferable over array indexing.    The fact you don't know how to obtain an index from an iterator doesn't mean it can't be done.   Sure, it's possible to find cases where indices are more effective. That doesn't mean one should default to using indices.

Answer (score 2):

An answer more to the underlying problem read from the comment:

> For example, I don't know how to write in a ranged-based for way:

```
for (int i = a.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) { a[i] = 2 * a[i+1]; }
```

You may change it to a generic one like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec1{ 1,2,3,4,5,6};
std::vector<int> vec2 = vec1;

int main()
{
    // generic code
    for ( auto it = vec1.rbegin()+1; it != vec1.rend(); it++ )
    {
       *it= 2* *(it-1);
    }

    // your code
    for (int i = vec2.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        vec2[i] = 2 * vec2[i+1];
    }

    for ( auto& el: vec1) { std::cout << el << std::endl; }
    for ( auto& el: vec2) { std::cout << el << std::endl; }
}
```

Not using range based for as it is not able to access relative to the position.

Comment: Thank you for this example! For now, I decided to stick to approach with iterators instead of using signed indices, because it solves the problem of compiler warnings. However, it is really difficult to read. For the first time, I read your example, I thought the code is wrong because I didn't realize that (it+1) actually move reverse iterator backwards in the array, while (it-1) moves it forward.

Comment: @BhavinChirag: Right, I also struggled with reverse operations on reverse iterators :-) But that's the way they work. So it is simply a question of using it more often...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding point 1: we hardly ever get those warnings here, because we use vectors' size_type where appropriate and/or cast to it if needed (with a 'checked' cast like boost::numeric_cast for safety). Is that not an option for you? Otherwise, write a function to do it for you, i.e. the non-const version would be something like

```
template<class T>
T& ati(std::vector<T>& v, std::int64_t i)
{
  return v.at(checked_cast<decltype(v)::size_type>(i));
}
```

And yes, inheriting is still a problem. And even if it weren't you'd break the definition of vector (and the Liskov substitution principle I guess), because the size_type is defined as

`an unsigned integral type that can represent any non-negative value of difference_type`

So it's down to composition, or a bunch of free functions for accessing with a signed size_type and a range check. Personally I'd go for the latter: less work, as easy to use, and you can still pass your vector to functions teaking vectors without problems.

Answer (score 0):

(This is more a comment than a real answer, but has some code, so...)

For the second part (range checking at runtime), a third option would be to use some macro trick:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  #define VECTOR_AT(v,i) v.at(i)
#else
  #define VECTOR_AT(v,i) v[i]
#endif
```

This can be used this way:

```
std::vector<sometype> vect(somesize);
VECTOR_AT(vect,i) = somevalue;
```

Of course, this requires editing your code in a quite non-standard way, which may not be an option. But it does the job.